# How to handle UnSubscription and expiry Date on play billing Library

Tags: android, play-billing-library

I'm working on an app which support subscription method my project is working completely fine and now I'm testing my app  but the problem which  struggling alot how to handle process  if user unsubscribed and his subscription time expired and also what to know litle bit about aknowledge with no consumable and if user user unsubcribed in trial days or user unsubscribed in his validity period. 
  here is the code where purchase will get process 
it will be called after query of skus where 
i process method like purchased or pending purchased.....
.......

```
private fun processPurchases(purchasesResult:  Set<Purchase>) =
        CoroutineScope(Job() + Dispatchers.IO).launch {
         //   Log.d(LOG_TAG, "processPurchases called")
            val validPurchases = HashSet<Purchase>(purchasesResult.size)
           // Log.d(LOG_TAG, "processPurchases newBatch content $purchasesResult")
            purchasesResult.forEach { purchase ->

                if (purchase.purchaseState == Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED) {
               //     subscriptionPrefs.setSubscriptionValue(true)
                   if(purchase.sku==PlayBillingUtils.MONTHLY_PACKAGE){
                               subscriptionPurchased.postValue("you have successfully subscribed to monthly package")
                               subscriptionPrefs.setSubscriptionValue(false)
                   }

                   else if (purchase.sku == PlayBillingUtils.THREE_MONTH_PACKAGE){
                       purchasingMutableLiveData.postValue("you have sucessfully subscribed to 3 month package")
                       subscriptionPrefs.setSubscriptionValue(false)


                   }


                    if (isSignatureValid(purchase)) {
                        validPurchases.add(purchase) }


                } else if (purchase.purchaseState == Purchase.PurchaseState.PENDING) {

                    purchasingMutableLiveData.postValue("Purchase Pending")
                }

            }


               // here the token get acknowledge 
            acknowledgeNonConsumablePurchasesAsync(purchasesResult.toList())
        }
```

Purchase all purchase Update will be invoked here but there is no method which will handle future call like when user unsubscribed or time expired want to know how to solve this problem

```
override fun onPurchasesUpdated(billingResult: BillingResult?, purchasemutableList: MutableList<Purchase>?) {


    billingResult?.let {
   when (billingResult.responseCode) {

        BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK -> {
            // will handle server verification, consumables, and updating the local cache
            purchasemutableList?.apply { processPurchases(this.toSet()) }
        }
       BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.ITEM_NOT_OWNED -> {
           subscriptionPrefs.setSubscriptionValue(false)

       }
        BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED -> {
            // item already owned? call queryPurchasesAsync to verify and process all such items
            println( billingResult.debugMessage)
            subscriptionPrefs.setSubscriptionValue(true)
            purchasingMutableLiveData.postValue("Item Already owned , enjoy ")
            queryPurchasesAsync()
        }
        BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.SERVICE_DISCONNECTED -> {
            purchasingMutableLiveData.postValue("Service Disconnected")
            connectToPlayBillingService()
        }

        BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.ITEM_NOT_OWNED->{
            purchasingMutableLiveData.postValue("Service Disconnected")
        }

        BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.SERVICE_TIMEOUT->{
            purchasingMutableLiveData.postValue("Service Time Out try again")
        }

        BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.USER_CANCELED->{
            subscriptionPrefs.setSubscriptionValue(false)
            purchasingMutableLiveData.postValue("service is cancelled")
        }

        else -> {
            println(billingResult.debugMessage)

        }
    }}
}
```

here i am passing subscription is aknowledge

```
 private fun acknowledgeNonConsumablePurchasesAsync(nonConsumables: List<Purchase>) {
    nonConsumables.forEach { purchase ->
        val params = AcknowledgePurchaseParams.newBuilder().setPurchaseToken(purchase
                .purchaseToken).build()
        playstoreBillingCLient.acknowledgePurchase(params) { billingResult ->
            when (billingResult.responseCode) {
                BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK -> {

                    println("acknowledged")
                }
                else ->
                    println( "acknowledgeNonConsumablePurchasesAsync response is ${billingResult.debugMessage}")
            }
        }

    }
}
```